# Google apps script Create gmail aliases for multiple accounts using single script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-admin-sdk, google-oauth

I am taking alias email information from users using a Google Form and have to create the said alias.
Google restricts the number of aliases per account to 30 hence I need to use different account to attach aliases to, and will be forwarding emails from those accounts to my original account.

I am not sure how to achieve this from a single company account. Do I have to now create a service account with Domain wide access or some sort of "super" script that creates aliases for the original account(one receiving all the forwarded emails) and the spillover accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are referring to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-user-aliases) about Aliases, then I think [Domain Wide Delegation of Authority in a service account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) will work on it. The main purpose of this is to access user data for users in your Google Apps domain.

Here is one example of [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).

> If you have a Google Apps domain—if you use Google Apps for Work, for
>   example—an administrator of the Google Apps domain can authorize an
>   application to access user data on behalf of users in the Google Apps
>   domain. For example, an application that uses the Google Calendar API
>   to add events to the calendars of all users in a Google Apps domain
>   would use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on
>   behalf of users. Authorizing a service account to access data on
>   behalf of users in a domain is sometimes referred to as "delegating
>   domain-wide authority" to a service account.

For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) for OAuth 2.0 for Service Account.

Comment: Aren't Client ID, private key are for external webapps? I'm trying to create these aliases using a google apps script attached to this Google Form. What would be the Client ID etc. in this case?